# iPad Launch Images and Orientation

Tags: ios, ipad, orientation

OK, I have a question regarding launch images on the iPad and orientation. Again, this is specifically regarding, launch images and has nothing to do with rotation/orientation once the application actually gets control.

Anyway, the Default.png resource is always loaded, regardless of orientation of the device, regardless of supported orientations, and regardless of Initial Interface Orientation. It just appears that the app is considered to be in Portrait until it is (possibly) auto-rotated later. I read something to this effect on the apple dev stuff, but given that there are launch images for these different orientations (Default-Landscape, Default-LandscapeLeft, etc.) I presumed that orientation was not fixed at launch.

The simple solution was to rotate my Default.png 90 degrees so that it is at least dimensionally correct, but that is not an acceptable solution unless it is the only solution. I did come across a reference to a folder called 'Resource-iPad' but have not been able to dig up much info in that regard.

Both the device and simulator seem consistent. I am targeting iPhone/iPad. Resources are in the root of main bundle, etc.

So, I must be missing something obvious, but I am not sure what and that is where you guys come in.

Thanks in advance,
Tom

Comment: Is the problem showing up when you run on an iPad, or only on the iPhone?

Answer (score 3):

If your app is universal, make sure you have two images for the iPad version -- one named "Default-Landscape~ipad.png" and one "Default-Portrait~ipad.png".  Be careful of the tilde vs. dash in the names.

If it isn't universal, then just "Default-Portrait.png" and "Default-Landscape.png" should work.  Not sure why it isn't working for you.  Maybe having "Default.png" and "Default-Landscape.png" isn't an acceptable combination for the OS, in which case change Default.png to Default-Portrait.png

Comment: John, thanks for calling out the ~ versus hyphen, my eyes totally missed that and having the correct resource names obviously helps. The overall problem still persists when I do not specify a value for initial orientation which i am thinking means that the launch is always portrait if no initial orientation is specified. This is even if portrait is NOT a supported orientation. Obviously I can live with this, just bugs me that I don't understand how it is really working underneath.

Answer (score 0):

I know that most (if not all) landscape Splash Screens are made by rotating the picture 90°. This usually reflects the intended orientation once the app loads, and helps the user turn their iOS device accordingly.

Comment: This makes sense if orientation is always set to portrait if no initial orientation is set. I do not want to set an initial orientation explicitly (don't care if the user holds it left or right at start time) when the app requires a landscape orientation but does not specify an initial orientation then it appears that it will start portrait, use Default.png, and when the app gets control it can rotate accordingly. In this case, Default-Landscape~ipad and related resources will *never* be used. I find this unusual from a design perspective and it leads me to believe that I am missing something.